# Bootstrap Carousel images display over one another

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When I use the following code, the image and caption for my second slide displays over those for the first slide and the slider stops working.  Below is my code, can anyone help me figure out how to move the second image and caption onto the second slide rather than the first?

```
<!--Carousel Code -->

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="itemactive">
      <img src="./clothes-hanger.png" alt="First slide">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>First title</h1>
       <br><strong><p>First paragraph</p></strong></br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      <img src="./clothes-hanger.png" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Second title</h1>
        <br><strong><p>Second paragraph</p></strong></br>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div class="item3">
<img src="" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have wrong css classes. Please check http://plnkr.co/edit/pb9ubz2Za4Ikpc1k0QzW?p=preview

e.g

for the first slide you should have

```
<div class="item active">
</div>
```

for the second just

```
<div class="item">
</div>
```

and for the third

```
<div class="item">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works in removing the image from slide 2, but now the sliders aren't working!

Comment: here is a working plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/0v5hihf9Wc4Zyd9aZ79Y?p=preview My bad i forgot to add jquery there. Now it works. Hope it helps